# How to call this in a function in a mootools class

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm having problems implementing classes in mootools since I can't use 'this' when I send methods in say `element.addEvent`.

Say I have this mootools class:

```
var Dude = new Class({

    highlightColor: '#f00',

    doStuff: function() {
        var parent = $('theParentId');

        new Element('div', {'html': 'Click me'})
            .inject(parent)
            .addEvent('click', function(){

                new Element('div', {'html': 'you clicked'})
                    .highlight(this.highlightColor);

            });
    },

});
```

This code will throw exception inside the addEvent method call, because `this` is suddenly is in another context. Is there some other way to get the object's highlightColor (or any other member that a mootools Class may have)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "MooTools way" would be to use the [`bindWithEvent`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Function#Function:bindWithEvent) function:

```
var Dude = new Class({

    highlightColor: '#f00',

    doStuff: function() {
        var parent = $('theParentId');

        new Element('div', {'html': 'Click me'})
            .inject(parent)
            .addEvent('click', function(event){

                new Element('div', {'html': 'you clicked'})
                    .highlight(this.highlightColor); // <- `this` refers to the 
            }.bindWithEvent(this));                  //    outer `this` value
    },
    //...
});
```

That method allows you to preserve the `this` value on a function, and pass additional arguments if necessary.

The first argument of the bound function, will refer to the [`Event`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Native/Event) object of the triggered event.

Comment: `bind` should be used instead of `bindWithEvent` - that would be "the mootools way" as core developers encourage not to use `bindWithEvent`.

Comment: @Oskar, well, `bindWithEvent` has been exactly made for this, [documentation](http://j.mp/cAoTn4) recommends its usage specifically when using addEvent: "This allows the function to be used in conjunction with Element:addEvent and arguments.", although I concede one benefit about using `bind`, the native implementations of the ECMAScript 5 standard `Function.prototype.bind` will be available soon on all browsers, and native implementations have always great performance. Anyway if Core developers don't encourage the usage of this method, a note in the docs would be helpful.

Comment: I agree with Oskar in that it's far more common to use `bind`--keeping scope to the class instance is _usually_ done like so. as far as my understanding goes, you don't need `bindWithEvent` here - all he accesses in the callback is the `this.highlightColor` property so keeping the scope to the class instance is enough. The event doesn't _need_ to be passed here at all as the callback already has direct access to it by definition. eg, `...click", this.methodName.bind(this)` will also pass the event object to the method as the first argument, so what's a good test case for `bindWithEvent`?

Comment: i built a little case to demonstrate when `bindWithEvent` needs to be used - when there are more arguments needing to be passed to the callback method than the event: http://jsfiddle.net/etCqH/

Comment: ahhhhh now i get it! thxs @Dimitar, sometimes an example is better than the documentation

Answer (score 3):

you need to bind the **this** reference to the function each time you use a function (on `addEvents` or `each`)

```
var Dude = new Class({

    highlightColor: '#f00',

    doStuff: function() {
        var parent = $('theParentId');

        new Element('div', {'html': 'Click me'})
            .inject(parent)
            .addEvent('click', function(){

                new Element('div', {'html': 'you clicked'})
                    .highlight(this.highlightColor);

            }.bind(this));
    }
});
```

be carefoul with the last coma on the function doStuff... firefox is like a mother it will foregive you but iexplorer is a bmf it will throw an error and wont tell you why

Answer (score 2):

@CMS was on a right track, but `bindWithEvent` is now deprecated and [documentation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/Function#Deprecated-Functions%3abindWithEvent) suggests using this code instead:

```
myElement.addEvent('click', function(e){
    myFunction.call(bind, e);
});
```

If you want to pass event binded element to one of your class methods you can do it like this:

```
var self = this; // 'this' is class reference
elements.addEvent('click', function(e){
    self.myClassMethod(this, e); // now 'this' is clicked element
});
```

Now you got the right element passed to your method and ready to manipulate on.